# Code Execution Directly in a React Function Component, When Multiple States Causes Multiple Re-Renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have component that uses both `useState()` and other custom hooks multiple times.

I want to act based on these state values. I could do that directly in the function component's body:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(false);
  const [otherState, setOtherState] = useState(false);
  const customHookValue = useCustomHook();

  if (someState) foo();
  const foo = () => setOtherState(!otherState);

  if (customHookValue > 10) bar();
  const bar = () => setSomeState(somestate > customHookValue);
}
```

However, every time `someState` changes (and a re-render happens) the second conditional also runs, causing `bar()` to run if the conditional passes. This feels unnatural. Logically, `bar()` should only run when `customHookValue` changes, as `someState` only changes if `customHookValue` has changed since last render.

In summary, a re-render caused by a change to `someState` should not cause a bunch of unrelated state setting functions to run again. Even though re-running them causes no change in the outcome of the program, it is not logically right. They only need to re-run when their corresponding conditional changes. It could effect performance.

This must be a common challenge in React. I am quite new to it, so I do not know what the approach to solve this would be.

**Questions**

1. How would I solve the above in the recommended manner?
2. Would I have to wrap every conditional in a `useEffect` or a `useMemo`?

---

**EDIT:**

Updated the second conditional, to make my question clearer (it should depend on customHook).

---

**CLARIFICATION:**

As it might not have been clear, my issue is as follows. When state changes, a re-render occurs. This causes all functions in the component's body to re-run. Now, if we have many `useState` in a component, and only one changes, a bunch of potentially unrelated state-changing and potentially expensive functions I have defined in the components body will run. These state-changing functions would only have to run if the state values they are trying to set has changed. If the values they are setting has not changed, it is unnecessary for them to run again. But, the re-render reruns all functions in the component's body regardless.

Comment: You have a side effect that needs to run depending on some state. That sounds like a perfect job for `useEffect` :)

Comment: @GaëlS Thank you for the reply. How do you determine it is a side-effect? I am just looking to set some state, depending on other state.

Comment: @GaëlS I updated the second conditional, as it should depend on `customHookValue`

Comment: Actually, it's more like "for which specific state does my component need to react and run specific pieces of code ? " kind of thinking you should have when using `useEffect`

Comment: So `useEffect` is exactly to to determine that some pieces of code should ONLY run when specific pieces of state changes?

Comment: Yes, thanks to it's second argument which is an array of dependencies to know on which variables changes an effect needs to run.

Comment: I read your question 10 times, I don't understand what is unnatural (in your opinion) here here? you have two conditions here, `someState` is either `true` or `false` that causes `foo` execute or not and the other a greater check, which also causes `bar` execute or not. and each re-render both conditions get checked and nre state sets which respectively causes another re-render? I still have problem with `unnatural` term you have used :)

Comment: @amirmousavi Thanks for reading through. The problem is that changing one state causes the function body to re-run, which runs a bunch of state changing functions that should only really run when the value they are setting state to had changed. If the value has not changed, these functions are executed unnecessarily by re-renders caused by unrelated state changes.

Comment: Added a clarification to the OP.

Comment: @GaëlS Why not use `useMemo` instead of `useEffect`? useMemo will only run a potentially expensive function if dependencies have changed. Seem identical to `useEffect`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like (as others have suggested) you want `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (someState) {
    setOtherState(!otherState)
  }
}, [someState, otherState])
useEffect(() => {
  if (customHookValue > 10) {
    setSomeState(someState > customHookValue)
  }
}, [customHookValue])
```

Since you only want the `setSomeState` to run if `customHookValue` changes, make it the only item in the dependencies array passed to `useEffect`.

The `exhaustive-deps` [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) will complain about the second useEffect, since the function depends on the value of `someState`, even though `someState` will only potentially change if `customHookValue` changes. I also wouldn't worry about things potentially affecting performance until they do. I don't know a ton about the internals of React, but it does some things under the hood to avoid re-renders it doesn't need to do, and can do multiple renders before an actual update is painted.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. So you aren't worried about a re-render unneccesarily running a bunch of functions and setting other state to unchanged values?

Comment: One thing: Why not use `useMemo`, instead of `useEffect`? It will only run a potentially expensive function when its dependencies change.

Comment: `useMemo` may help things - it isn't "`useEffect` but doesn't run as often", though. I personally am still getting used to hooks as well, and haven't spent enough time trying `useMemo` too much as I haven't had any performance issues so far without using it. With regards to unnecessarily running a bunch of functions, the answer is likely similar to the answer for this FAQ question: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#are-hooks-slow-because-of-creating-functions-in-render